# Create a pair based on conditions from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
a:
TransID    Currency
1                 CAD
2                 USD

b:
TransID    Currency
3                 CAD
4                 EUR
```

The condition is if two TransIDs have a common currency, print the output as a pair of the two, i.e. in this case the output should be -

(1,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `merge` and then obtain lists from the results:

```
a.merge(b, on='Currency').filter(like='Trans').values.tolist()
# [[1, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I use multiple conditions? i.e. what if the two dataframes had an amount column as well and I wanted to display only pairs where the amount in a was less than the amount in b along with the first condition of the currencies being the same??